# Maven dependency tree different from M2E's Dependency Hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm building a Java Project `MaterialsDep` that is a plugin for project `craftbukkit` [loaded in my workspace and a direct dependency of MaterialsDep of type jar and scope compile]. Looking at MaterialsDep's pom's dependency hierarchy in eclipse all jars needed by CB show up as resolved and listed correctly. However running `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` on project AP only copies direct dependencies and nothing else.

Running dependency:tree shows:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree (default-cli) @ MaterialsDep ---
[INFO] MaterialsDep:MaterialsDep:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar:1.3.1-R1.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.pircbotx:pircbotx:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] \- org.bukkit:bukkit:jar:1.3.1-R1.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

which are the direct dependencies.

How should I go about ensuring that `craftbukkit`'s dependency are recognized and copied ?

**[EDIT]**

`dependency:tree` for craftbukkit:

```
[INFO] org.bukkit:craftbukkit:jar:1.3.1-R1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.bukkit:bukkit:jar:1.3.1-R1.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.bukkit:minecraft-server:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- jline:jline:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.avaje:ebean:jar:2.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.9:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:provided
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit-dep:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

By configuring the `dependency` plugin correctly. The property [excludeTransitive](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeTransitive) defines whether transitive dependencies will be ignored or not. Make sure it's value is `false`.

`mvn help:effective-pom` might help to find out how the plugin is configured.

**[EDIT]** `copy-dependencies` will only copy what `dependency:tree` shows. As you can see in the output above, `craftbukkit` itself doesn't have any further dependencies. My guess is that all dependencies in `craftbukkit`'s POM have `<optional>true</optional>`.

If that is the case, then you will have to mention all of them again in your POM.

Comment: effective-pom shows there are no excludes defined or includes, which should make it default to "include all" transitives if I understand the documentation correctly. I'll give it a go forcing it to false just in case.

Comment: Also look into the POM of `craftbukkit`. `copy-dependencies` will ignore `optional` dependencies.

Comment: I've added the dependency tree for craftbukkit above. I didn't expect the `provided` dependencies to be copied, but I did expect `compile` ones to show up. Looking at CraftBukkit's effective-pom there's no use of optional anywhere.

Comment: Odd. Do you see the correct POM when you double click on the dependency in the m2e editor (the tree view, not the XML)? Maybe the POM in your .m2 folder is out of date?

Comment: Okay ... I have no idea what is going on here. Maybe try to run `mvn` with `-X` to see the full configuration of the `copy-dependencies` plugin. Maybe you can find something in there.